ESP-IDF SPI write function does not work properly, read functions works
The thing is that I need to implement to functions: spiRegisterRead(uint16_t reg_addr) and spiRegisterWrite(uint_16t reg_addr, uit32_t reg_value). These two functions have a main goal of reading the full 32-bit register and writing to it. The read function works as expected, but the write function does not write anything. I have tried multiple versions of that, including using the TXDATA instead of TXBUFFERS etc.
Working spiRegisterRead():
uint32_t spiRegisterRead(uint16_t reg_addr) {

    uint8_t rx_buffer[5];

    spi_transaction_t t;
    
    memset(&t, 0, sizeof(spi_transaction_t)); 

    t.cmd = SPI_READ_OPCODE;
    t.addr = reg_addr;
    t.length = 5 * 8; // length byte
    t.rxlength = 5 * 8;
    t.rx_buffer = rx_buffer;
    t.tx_buffer = NULL;

    // Transmit the dummy bytes to read the actual data
    spi_device_transmit(spi, &t);

    // Combine the received bytes into a 32-bit value
    uint32_t reg_value = ((uint64_t)rx_buffer[1] << 24) |
                ((uint64_t)rx_buffer[2] << 16) | ((uint64_t)rx_buffer[3] << 8) | (rx_buffer[4]);

    return reg_value;
}


Not working spiRegisterWrite():
uint8_t spiRegisterWrite(uint16_t reg_addr, uint32_t reg_value, uint32_t * pointer) {

    uint8_t tx_buffer[4];
    //uint8_t rx_buffer[4];
    
    tx_buffer[0] = (uint8_t)reg_value;
    tx_buffer[1] = (uint8_t)(reg_value >> 8);
    tx_buffer[2] = (uint8_t)(reg_value >> 16);
    tx_buffer[3] = (uint8_t)(reg_value >> 24);

    //memcpy(tx_buffer, &reg_value, sizeof(uint32_t));

    printf("Writing %lX into %X\n", reg_value, reg_addr);

    spi_transaction_t t;
    
    memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t)); 

    t.cmd = SPI_WRITE_OPCODE; // Not sure
    t.addr = reg_addr;
    t.length = 4 * 8; // length byte + 4*bytes data 
    //t.flags = SPI_TRANS_USE_TXDATA;
    //t.rxlength = 4 * 8;
    //t.rx_buffer = NULL;
    t.tx_buffer = tx_buffer;
    //memcpy(t.tx_data, &reg_value, sizeof(uint32_t));

    spi_device_polling_transmit(spi, &t);

    /*if (pointer != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(pointer, rx_buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));
    }*/


    // uint8_t data_to_send = 0x45;
    // spi_transaction_t t;
    // memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t));       //Zero out the transaction
    // t.length=8;                     //Command is 8 bits
    // t.tx_buffer=&data_to_send;      //The data is the cmd itself
    // t.user=(void*)1;                //D/C needs to be set to 1
    // t.addr = 0x0808;
    // t.cmd = SPI_WRITE_OPCODE;
    // spi_device_transmit(spi, &t);

    return 0;
}

In the comments above you can see, what has been tested already.
Here is the intialisation of SPI:
void spi_init() {
    esp_err_t ret;
    
    // Configure the SPI bus
    spi_bus_config_t buscfg = {
        .miso_io_num = PIN_NUM_MISO,
        .mosi_io_num = PIN_NUM_MOSI,
        .sclk_io_num = PIN_NUM_CLK,
        .quadwp_io_num = -1,
        .quadhd_io_num = -1,
        .max_transfer_sz = 4096,
    };

    // Initialize the SPI bus
    ret = spi_bus_initialize(HSPI_HOST, &buscfg, 1);
    assert(ret == ESP_OK);

    // Configure the SPI device
    spi_device_interface_config_t devcfg = {
        .clock_speed_hz = 10 * 1000 * 1000,    // Clock out at 10 MHz
        .mode = 0,                             // SPI mode 0
        
        .spics_io_num = PIN_NUM_CS,            // CS pin
        .queue_size = 7,                     
        .pre_cb = NULL,
        .post_cb = NULL,
        .command_bits = 8,                     // Important! 
        .address_bits = 16                     // Important!
    };

    // Attach the SPI device to the SPI bus
    ret = spi_bus_add_device(HSPI_HOST, &devcfg, &spi);
    assert(ret == ESP_OK);
}


I develop this driver to interact with TCAN4550. As a matter of testing the driver, I wrote the following code:
uint32_t check;
    
    value = spiRegisterRead(0x0808);

    printf("Reg content: %lX\n", value);

    spiRegisterWrite(0x0808, 0x87650000, &check);

    usleep(1000);

    value = spiRegisterRead(0x0808);

    printf("Prev reg value: %lX\n", check);
    printf("New reg content: %lX\n", value);

The register I am writing to is intended as a testing register for writing and reading.

I don't understand your length values (e.g. 4 * 8 instead of 4). Unless they are bit lengths? But, for RX you do: to.rx_length = xxx;. Don't you need t.tx_length = 4 * 8; in the TX code?

Lengths are in bits. t.length is for TX and t.rxlength is for RX. Refer to official ESP-IDF spi master docs.

Here the comment and code seem to disagree: t.length = 4 * 8; // length byte + 4*bytes data.

What ends up in rx_buffer[0] and why is that a special case? Why isn't that byte present when doing tx? That doesn't make much sense - SPI is full duplex, it transmits and receives at the same time, so always the same amount of data for tx and rx.
